# JavaScript: formatting decimal that starts at hundredths and below

Tags: javascript

We need to handle values like this

```
0.00 //Show as is
0.45 //Show as is
0.002 //Need to show 0.002 or 0.0020 which ever is doable
0.0003 //Need to show 0.0003 or 0.00030 which ever is doable
0.00004 //Need to show 0.00004 or 0.000040 which ever is doable
0.00234567 //Need to show 0.0023
```

We are not able to make it work on fractional part where a non zero value started at thousandth place and always ended up displaying `0.00` as if it is totally a zero value. We still want the above formatting with comma when dealing with whole number but also allowing us to format when non zero starts beyond hundredths place.

Further sample

```
0.0492 // 0.04 or 0.05 which ever is doable
700.356 // 700.35 or 700.36 which ever is doable
54232.542234 // 54,232.54
1110.000000500000004 // 1110.0000005 or 1110.00 which ever is doable
```

ChatGPT solution on this is messy and doesn't cover all the cases presented above.

```js
function formatCurrency(number) {
  const decimalPlaces = (Math.abs(number) % 1).toString().split('.')[1]?.length || 0;
  let minimumFractionDigits = decimalPlaces;
  let maximumFractionDigits = decimalPlaces;

  // Special case for numbers greater than or equal to 1
  if (Math.abs(number) >= 1) {
    minimumFractionDigits = 2;
    maximumFractionDigits = 2;
  } else if (decimalPlaces > 2) {
    minimumFractionDigits = 4;
    maximumFractionDigits = 4;
  } else if (decimalPlaces === 0) {
    minimumFractionDigits = 2;
    maximumFractionDigits = 2;
  }

  const formattedNumber = number.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'USD',
    minimumFractionDigits: minimumFractionDigits,
    maximumFractionDigits: maximumFractionDigits,
  });

  return formattedNumber.replace(/\.0+$/, ''); // Remove trailing zeros
}

console.log(formatCurrency(0.00));
console.log(formatCurrency(0.45));
console.log(formatCurrency(0.002));
console.log(formatCurrency(0.0003));
console.log(formatCurrency(0.00004));
console.log(formatCurrency(0.00234567));
console.log(formatCurrency(54232.542234));
console.log(formatCurrency(1110.000000500000004));
```

To support that it is possible, this is how to do it in Kotlin.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat
import java.text.NumberFormat
import java.util.Locale
import kotlin.math.abs

/**
 * Utility class for all object under Number superclass
 * */
object NumbersUtil {

    private const val DEFAULT_TWO_DECIMAL = "0.00"

    /**
     * Formatter that supports value with fractional lower than hundredths.
     * Ideal use for handling currency value
     * */
    fun formatFractional(number: Number?): String {

        var isNegative = false

        if (number == null)
            return "0.00"

        var nonNullNumber = number.toDouble()

        if (nonNullNumber < 0) {
            isNegative = true
            nonNullNumber = abs(number.toDouble())
        }

        var temp = nonNullNumber - nonNullNumber.toInt()
        temp *= 100
        var nrDec = 2

        val format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US)

        if (temp >= 1.0) {
            format.maximumFractionDigits = nrDec
            return if (isNegative) "-${format.format(nonNullNumber)}" else format.format(nonNullNumber)
        }

        while (temp < 1.0 && nrDec < 15) {
            temp *= 10
            nrDec++
        }

        if ((temp * 10 % 10) != 0.0) {
            nrDec++
        }

        format.maximumFractionDigits = nrDec

        return if (isNegative) "-${format.format(nonNullNumber)}" else format.format(nonNullNumber)

    }

}

fun main() {
    println(NumbersUtil.formatFractional(0.00004))
}
```

The cleanest we can get is this, but this does not work well for all sample input vs expected output.

```
const numbers = [0.00, 0.45, 0.002, 0.0003, 0.00004, 0.00234567, 0.0492, 7000.356, -0.18172079106424363];
const options = { 
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 10
};
numbers.forEach(num => {
  const formatted = Number(num).toLocaleString('en', options);
  console.log(formatted);
});
```

Comment: Why are you removing the trailing zeros if you need them kept in? Also please explain the requirements? Right now they seem to be arbitrary

Comment: @evolutionxbox, it is already and clearly stated with samples that includes input data and expected output. What exactly are you looking for? Removing the trailing doesn't make any difference actually, the code still not working as expected. I will add a Kotlin function that performs the above requirements to show it is possible but seems difficult for JS.

Answer (score -1):

This might be the answer you are looking for:

```js
function formatNumber(num) {
    // Function to remove trailing zeroes
    function removeZeroes(number) {
        return number.replace(/(\.\d*?)0{0,2}$/, '$1');
    }

    // Function to add commas to a number
    function addCommas(number) {
        return number.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }

    if (num < 1) {
        return removeZeroes(num.toFixed(4));
    } else {
        return addCommas(num.toFixed(2));
    }
}


// Test cases

console.log(formatNumber(0.00));
console.log(formatNumber(0.45));
console.log(formatNumber(0.002));
console.log(formatNumber(0.0003));
console.log(formatNumber(0.00004));
console.log(formatNumber(0.00234567));
console.log(formatNumber(0.0492));
console.log(formatNumber(700.356));
console.log(formatNumber(54232.542234));
```

I recently learned somethiing related to this so I myself can use it aswell.

Comment: Not working with `0.00004`, the `toFixed(4)` can be dynamic here but should not end up like this `0.0000400000000`